# ":first-letter" pseudo element - remove spacing on mobile

Tags: css, mobile

I want to style the first letter in a different style, it works in every browser on desktop and with every browser-width, but on mobile (tested on iphone and windows phone) I have some strange spacing at the top and the bottom of the letter.

desktop:

[image]

mobile:

[image]

This is my CSS:

```
p:first-of-type:first-letter {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font-size: 5.6em;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-top: 8px;
  padding-right: .2em;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/herrfischer/pen/dMdvMN).

Answer (score 0):

I managed it by adding:

```
line-height: .6em;
```